# Problem with truncation of floating point values in DBSlayer

Tags: mysql, json, dbslayer

When I run a query through DBslayer http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer the floating point results are 
truncated to a total of six digits (plus decimal point and negative 
sign when needed).

{ ... "lat":52.2228,"lng":-2.19906, ... }

When I run the same query in MySQL, the results are as expected.

| 52.22280884 | -2.19906425 |

Firstly, am I correct in identifying DBSlayer as the cause of this 
effect?  (Or the JSON library it uses, etc.)

Secondly, is this floating point precision configurable within DBSlayer?

Thanks,

Chris.

P.S. Ubuntu 9.10, x86_64

Path: . 
URL: http://dbslayer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk 
Repository Root: http://dbslayer.googlecode.com/svn 
Repository UUID: 5df2be84-4748-0410-afd4-f777a056bd0c 
Revision: 65 
Node Kind: directory 
Schedule: normal 
Last Changed Author: dgottfrid 
Last Changed Rev: 65 
Last Changed Date: 2008-03-28 22:52:46 +0000 (Fri, 28 Mar 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem.

There are several places where DBSlayer uses printf's %g to format doubles.  This gives only 6 significant digits.

Replacing all of these occurrences with %.15g, and recompiling, has solved the problem.